# Include sources from Java library submodule in Android library project aar artifact

Tags: java, android, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have a **java library** submodule holding interfaces which are used in another **android library** submodule. The problem is that the sources of the java library module are compiled but not included in the `aar` artifact of the android library project.

How can I include the sources of the java library in the android library  `aar` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up including the source files of the java library directly into the android library project using:

```
sourceSets {
        main{
            java {
                srcDir("../java_library/src")
            }
        }
    }
```

Only this way the sources are included in the aar file. Still will be great to know if it is possible using simple gradle dependency management.